# Javascript / Angular calculate total for object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting my head around Angular, and brushing up on my Javascript so making a little cart app.

What I want to do is show a line total for each of the lines in the order, as well as the overall order total. I can work out the order total no problem, but having a little trouble doing the line total part (per line).

So, it should show:

```
Order Total: £45

|------------------------------------------|
| Product | Qty | Price | Discount | Total |
|------------------------------------------|
| iPod    | 1   | 10    | 5        | 5     |
| laptop  | 2   | 20    | 0        | 40    |
|------------------------------------------|
```

It's the individual line totals I am struggling with.

Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/e1ujuq31/3/

```
<div class="container" ng-app="orderApp">
 <h1>Create a new order</h1>

<div ng-Controller="CartForm">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>List Price</td>
                <td>£{{ total() }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>List Discounts</td>
                <td>£0.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>One Off Discount</td>
                <td>£0.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td>£{{ total() }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h2>Order Lines</h2>

        <div ng-repeat="line in orderHeader.lines">List price:
            <input type="number" ng-model="line.cost" ng-required class="input-mini">Qty:
            <input type="number" ng-model="line.qty" ng-required class="input-mini">Discount:
            <input type="number" ng-model="line.discount" ng-required class="input-mini">Line Total: {{ line.total }} <a href ng-click="removeLine($index)" class="btn btn-small">Remove</a>

        </div> <a href ng-click="addLine()" class="btn btn-small">Add Line</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var orderApp = angular.module('orderApp', []);

orderApp.controller('CartForm', function ($scope) {

$scope.orderHeader = {
    list_total: 0,
    list_discount: 0,
    oo_discount: 0,
    total: 0,
    lines: []
};

$scope.addLine = function () {
    $scope.orderHeader.lines.push({
        qty: 1,
        description: '',
        cost: 20,
        discount: 0,
        total: parseFloat(this.cost * this.qty - this.discount)
    });
}


$scope.removeLine = function (index) {
    $scope.orderHeader.lines.splice(index, 1);
},

$scope.total = function () {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.orderHeader.lines, function (line) {
        total += (line.qty * line.cost) - line.discount;
    });
    return total;
}

});
```

Currently, the line total is showing NaN / null. Any ideas?

Comment: where is listPrice()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e1ujuq31/4/)

```
 $scope.lineTotal = function (line) {
        return (line.qty * line.cost) - line.discount;
    };


  <input type="number" ng-model="line.discount" ng-required class="input-mini">Line Total: {{ lineTotal(line) }} <a href ng-click="removeLine($index)" class="btn btn-small">Remove</a>
```